# kendoGrid dataSource html table

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I build a HTML table in java script and would like to set it to the dataSource of kendoGrid but it is not working

Most of the example are using array but I would like to use this custom html table.

```
Code ASPX
<div id="grid"></div>

JS
 table += tr + "</table>";

                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read: table
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        groupable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            refresh: true,
                            pageSizes: true,
                            buttonCount: 5
                        },
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no details on the structure of your table, however here is a simple example with one row and column headers, to be able to set the dataSource to a HTML table you would need to use some sort of kendo custom template, or alternatively have a function to traverse through all the nodes in the table and then set that to an array and use that in the dataSource field.

```
<table id="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-field="make">Car Make</th>
            <th data-field="model">Car Model</th>
            <th data-field="year">Year</th>
            <th data-field="category">Category</th>
            <th data-field="airconditioner">Air Conditioner</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Volvo</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>2010</td>
            <td>Saloon</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            height: 550,
            sortable: true
        });
    });
</script>
```